# Setting Keystore file location using system properties which is inside resources directory of Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, ssl, spring-boot

I have my .jks file placed inside resources directory of spring boot app, now i need to configure the key store using system property. Have tried various ways like setting the property using `System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "abc.jks");` `System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "classpath:abc.jks");`, nothing worked other than giving full path in the file system `System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "D:/../abc.jks");`.How to configure the system property values, so that it works. I dont want it to be enabled for the embedded tomcat. Just want to set it up to the jvm.

Comment: "Nothing worked" is not a useful statement.  **What** didn't work?  You don't provide enough information to solve your problem. Post details about your setup.  Post what you have tried.  Post your error messages.

Comment: System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "target/classes/abc.jks");

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

application.properties

```
server.port: 8443
server.ssl.key-store: classpath:${KEYSTORE:keystore.p12}
server.ssl.key-store-password: password
server.ssl.keyStoreType: PKCS12
server.ssl.keyAlias: tomcat
```

This will look for a system property KEYSTORE if not it will default to keystore.p12, so the application can be run like:

```
java -jar target/spring-boot-https-1.0.jar
```

or

```
java -DKEYSTORE=anotherKeystore.p12 -jar target/spring-boot-https-1.0.jar
```

That's all you need to do, if the keystore.p12 is in resources directory, to test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class HelloControllerIT {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    private RestTemplate template;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        createTemplateFromKeyStore("keystore.p12");
    }

    @Test
    public void getHello() throws Exception {
        ResponseEntity<String> response = template.getForEntity("https://localhost:" + port + "/", String.class);
        assertThat(response.getBody(), equalTo("Greetings from Spring Boot!"));
    }

    private void createTemplateFromKeyStore(String keyStoreName) {
        try {
            InputStream keyStoreInputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(keyStoreName);
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            keyStore.load(keyStoreInputStream, null);

            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom()
                    .loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, "password".toCharArray())
                    .loadTrustMaterial(keyStore, new TrustAllStrategy()).build();

            HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLContext(sslContext)
                    .setSSLHostnameVerifier(NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE).build();

            HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
            requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);

            template = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
        } catch (IOException | GeneralSecurityException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

see [example project](https://github.com/gregclinker/spring-boot-https)

Having said all that you would be better off using [spring profiles](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-profile-based-properties-and-yaml-example/) and have multiple application.properties

```
application-dev.properties
application-prod.properties
```

with different values in them and control from the command line

```
java -Dspring.profiles.active=dev -jar target/spring-boot-https-1.0.jar
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i dont want it to be set to the embedded tomcat, rather want to set it to the jvm.